# How to log what an FTP user does with Pure-FTPD and Apache?

Tags: ftp, logging, pureftpd

I have a VPS with Apache and Pure-FTPD and I'm wondering if it's possible to log every action that an FTP user does (such as viewing files and editing them)? If this is possible, please let me know how I can do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enable

```
VerboseLog yes
```

in your pureftpd.conf. This logs all actions.

Alternatively you can use the `-d` or `--verboselog` commandline options at the startup of pureftpd.

Where these logs go depends on your distribution. This is often /var/log/messages or a separate pureftpd.log.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried what you said and it seems to work. Would you happen to know if enabling the VerboseLog takes a performance hit on the server, or if it creates any other problems? Thanks.

Comment: Besides the amount of writes because of the logs, I would not expect to see any side effects. Because logs are usually buffered writes, I wouldn't expect an impact on performance as well. But it depends on the amount of FTP load you already have.

Comment: This logging is not very verbose, I wanted to see the transfer mode and DNS client used to connect with as well.